# What unit is the timeout parameter in BluetoothSocket on Android/Java?

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

In the BluetoothSocket class on Android/Java, there is an accept method with a integer timeout parameter. The documentation does not specify what the unit of the timeout parameter is: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothServerSocket.html#accept(int)

The method description is:

```
accept(int timeout)
```

Does anyone know what unit the timeout parameter should be in? Seconds? Milliseconds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are milliseconds

Based on the comment of the involved class here
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/bluetooth/BluetoothSocket.java#461

Comment: But as it also shows there, the `accept` method has got package visibility; so, why are you invoking the method anyway?

Comment: @AndyTurner The OP user asked about this method https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/bluetooth/BluetoothServerSocket.java#157, which turns out to call the internal private `BluetoothSocket.accept(int timeout)` method where the log indicates it referes to milliseconds. The documentation is lacking because BluetoothServerSocket is public